How to make outer rounded border CSS/TailwindCSS
how can i style the border on the bottom left "contact" button like this?(https://i.sstatic.net/xSC2oPiI.png)
`
    <div id="image" className="absolute top-32 left-0 w-full h-full bg-[#DFE2EC] rounded-[60px] z-0">
      <Image
        src={Combined}
        alt="background-image"
        className="object-contain w-full h-full"
      />
    </div>

    <div id="content" className="relative z-10 w-full h-full">
      <div id="container" className="max-w-8xl mx-auto">
        <div id="content" className="relative md:flex-row">
          <div id="text-content" className="relative flex-col md:pl-[157px] md:pt-[110px] md:w-[60%] z-10">
            <h1 className="font-bold text-[#012D9A] relative font-spaceGrotesk text-2xl md:text-[80px] md:leading-[100px]">
              Expert Construction Service for Every Project
            </h1>
            <p className="font-epilogue md:pt-[30px] md:mr-[30px] w-3/4 md:text-2xl text-left text-[#5F5F5F]">
              General Contractor, Civil Electrical, Power Systems, and Telecommunication Network
            </p>
            <div id="clients" className="grid grid-cols-2 gap-0 w-4/5 md:pr-[200px] md:pt-[40px]">
              <h1 className="font-epilogue text-[#5F5F5F] font-semibold md:text-[44px] md:leading-[52px]">20+</h1>
              <h1 className="font-epilogue font-semibold md:text-[44px] md:leading-[52px] text-[#5F5F5F]">10+</h1>
              <p className="font-epilogue text-[#5F5F5F]  md:text-[24px]">Clients</p>
              <p className="font-epilogue text-[#5F5F5F]  md:text-[24px]">Project Completed</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="overlay" className="relative p-6 min-h-screen">
      <div id="top-left" className={`absolute bottom-0 left-0 z-50 w-8 h-8 bg-red-500 [mask-image:radial-gradient(circle_at_100%_100%, transparent_71%, black_71%)]`} />
      <div id="top-right" className={`absolute bottom-0 left-0 z-50 w-8 h-8 bg-red-500 [mask-image:radial-gradient(circle_at_0%_100%, transparent-[71%], black-[71%])]`} />
    </div>
  </section>`

this is my current approach to this, how can i style it better and is there better approach to this? and alsoe the mask-image styling doesnt work because tbh i dont know what im doing

hey thanks for the comments but i meant was the masking of the background

Oups, hello, you probably need a mask which tailwind doesn't manage. but via a custom rule https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#arbitrary-properties ,  you could do something alike : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/jOjgNWE

yes thanks for the reply, how about the outer radius and inner radius cause i cant seem to do it like in my screenshot

there's actually a good explanation here how it works and how you may need to set the rounded part. https://css-tricks.com/gooey-effect/
